# SSL connection string for Azure PostgreSQL - correct syntax

Tags: vba, postgresql, azure, ssl, adodb

I have a Microsoft Excel workbook which I connect to a PostgreSQL db.  I have had this working with the db on localhost for some time.

I have now moved my db to Azure PostgreSQL.  I have successfully reconfigured my queries/connections to pull data into the spreadsheet (by setting up a DSN in 'ODBC Data sources 64 bit') with SSL set to require.

The workbook includes some vba to write data back to the database.  I am getting the error:

> Runtime error: '-2147467259 (80004005)': FATAL: SSL connection is
>   required. Please specify SSL options and retry.

The error throws on the `dbConnPublic.Open sqlConnString` line

The relevant parts of the code look like this:

```
Sub WriteRowToDB()

' Define connectivity
Dim dbConnPublic As New ADODB.Connection
Dim sqlConnString As String

sqlConnString = OpenConnection()
dbConnPublic.Open sqlConnString

End Sub


Public Function OpenConnection() As String

'Define connection objects and terms
Dim sqlConnString As String

Dim myDriver As String: myDriver = "{PostgreSQL ANSI(x64)}"
Dim myServer As String: myServer = "djm-main-01.postgres.database.azure.com"

Dim myDatabase As String: myDatabase = "postgres"
Dim myUserName As String: myUserName = "djmmain01admin@djm-main-01"
Dim myPassword As String: myPassword = "[my password]" ' this replaced by the real password

' Open connection
sqlConnString = "Driver={PostgreSQL ANSI(x64)};" & _
                "DSN=postgres;" & _
                "Server=" & myServer & ";" & _
                "Port=5432;" & _
                "UID=" & myUserName & ";" & _
                "PWD=" & myPassword & ";" & _
                "Database=" & myDatabase & ";" & _




 "ssl=true;READONLY=0;PROTOCOL=6.4;FAKEOIDINDEX=0;SHOWOIDCOLUMN=0;ROWVERSIONING=0;SHOWSYSTEMTABLES=1"

OpenConnection = sqlConnString

End Function
```

I have tried every combination of ssl=true, ssl=required, sslmode=required, using two parameters and three, some with caps, some lowercase, some mixed.  cannot find anything that makes a difference. Also not sure if this syntax is Azure, PostgreSQL or ADODB.

Note that I can also successfully connect to the Azure db using DBeaver and command line psql from Windows, using SSL.

Answer (score 1):

Hi anyone who is watching.  So I worked this out.

Actually very simple, the required parameter is `sslmode=require`.  It is case sensitive.  I must have somehow missed this from my permutations.  And therefore assume that the syntax is determined by the PostgreSQL ODBC driver.

This resource helped:
https://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql-odbc-driver-psqlodbc/

Additional gotcha to watch out for :  when the password is included in the connection string, then any non-alphanumerics need to be url encoded which I wasn't thinking about,so my system generated password with an exclamation mark had to be converted to %21.  I got the encoded password from the User DSN at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI\`

However I have now changed the password so that it does not use non-alphanumerics.

Hope this is useful.

Comment: Just to document this in case someone has the same problem, the parameter is "sslmode=require"